# Mongo - How to update multiple documents with different value in single query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to write a query for updating multiple documents in a single query, Please suggest me possible ways.

Following is my mongo document.

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204cd"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "ABC",
        "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204ce"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "DEF",
        "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204cf"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "GHI",
        "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204d0"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "userType": "admin"
    }
]
```

I've following the updated object in code, how can I update that in a database with the query.

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204cd"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "ABC123",
        "color":"red"
        "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204ce"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "DEF123",
        "color":"blue"
        "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204cf"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "GHI123",
        "color":"green"
        "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204d0"),
        "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
        "name" : "XYZ123",
        "color":"rgb(14,256,12, 1)"
        "userType": "admin"
    }
]
```

Please suggest me the proper ways, or We can do it or not?

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: Nothing, I tried with `updateMany` and with `upsert: true`.

Comment: what type of array your are passing to update the documents? Update your question and post the payload array by which you want to update the multiple documents

Comment: From same as output object. just want to compare `_id` and update all data

Comment: Try my this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801033/mongoose-add-multiple-object-to-array-if-not-exist-based-on-key/51808332#51808332

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You basically need [**`bulkWrite`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) operation in mongodb

```
const array = [
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204cd"),
    "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
    "name" : "ABC123",
    "color":"red"
    "userType": "admin"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204ce"),
    "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
    "name" : "DEF123",
    "color":"blue"
    "userType": "admin"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204cf"),
    "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
    "name" : "GHI123",
    "color":"green"
    "userType": "admin"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f0a2ca1f6633032c204d0"),
    "parent_id" : ObjectId("5b0f09e1a1f6633032c204cc"),
    "name" : "XYZ123",
    "color":"rgb(14,256,12, 1)"
    "userType": "admin"
  }
]
```

And the final query

```
Model.bulkWrite(
  array.map((data) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: data._id },
        update: { $set: data }
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Comment: @TBE For query OR for the above data in `array`?

Comment: For the query, you have an un-needed closing brace. 
Your last line shall be `)` instead of `})`