# Update Many with mongoose - Array of update objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Let say i have the following array:

```
[
    {_id: 1, status: "Active"},
    {_id: 2, status: "Delete"},
    {_id: 10, status: "Pause"},
    {_id: 20, status: "Active"}
]
```

And i want to update the field `status` in collection `users` with a single mongoDB call using **mongoose**. (Update only documents with _id = 1,2,10,20)

My Schema can look like this:

```
var userScheme = new Schema({
    fname : String,
    lname : String,
    status : String,
    email : String
});
db.model('user', userScheme);
```

NOTE: I want to use `updateMany` and not `update`

Comment: This is what  you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800392/mongo-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-different-value-in-single-query/51821792#51821792

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who will want a complete example instead of being re-route to other question, here is my answer which is based on @Ashh 's answer.

```
db.model("user").bulkWrite(
                usersArray.map((data) =>
                    ({
                        updateOne: {
                            filter: { _id: data._id },
                            update: { $set: {status: data.status} }
                        }
                    })
                )
            );
```